# How do I implement server affinity or sticky sessions on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, session-state, sticky

My application wishes to have:

1. Automatic scalability

   - I want App Engine to spin up new instances of my app when traffic increases
   - When instances become idle, I want App Engine to shut them down
2. Client/server affinity

   - After an initial client->server HTTP request, I want clients
     to be able to connect to the same appserver, so that the appserver
     can maintain a bunch of client state
   - State may be updated frequently (in order to support real-time interactions),
     so memcache+datastore based persistence is not desirable.
   - The server may need to make decisions based on the state of multiple clients,
     e.g. real time multi-player game

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve these goals using App Engine backends (long-running, configurable, addressable, persistent servers):

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/

#### Python implementation

1. Configure a backend to be both *public* and *dynamic*

   ```
   # backends.yaml

   backends:
   - name: foo
     instances: 20
     options: public, dynamic
   ```
2. In addition to deploying your app in usual way:

   ```
   appcfg.py update .
   ```

   remember to deploy you backend:

   ```
   appcfg.py backends . update
   ```
3. For the initial connection, have your client use the
   non-instance specific backend hostname, e.g.:

   ```
   foo.your_app_id.appspot.com
   ```

   App Engine will route your request to available backend
   instance, after optionally starting a new backend instance.
4. In the request handling code on the server, use the backends
   API to determine which instance is handling the request and
   return to the client a instance specific URL.

   ```
   from google.appengine.api import backends

   import webapp2

   class GetPersistentUrlHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

     def get(self):
       """Return the current backend's instance-specific URL."""

       my_url = backends.get_url(instance=backends.get_instance())
       self.response.write(my_url)

   app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
     ('/get_peristent_url', GetPersistentUrlHandler),
   ], debug=True)
   ```
5. Client makes subsequent connections to the instance specific
   backend URL:

   ```
   http://3.foo.your_app_id.appspot.com
   ```

   *Note: when using https be sure to replace subdomain dots with `-dot-`
   in order to avoid SSL certificate issues.*

   ```
   https://3-dot-foo.your_app_id.appspot.com
   ```

#### Limitations

1. Backends do not live forever and may be shutdown unexpectedly and without notice
2. The number of backends your application can have is currently limited

Answer (score 4):

To complement Adam's good answer: you don't need server affinity in GAE, because data stored in the HTTP session is not held in memory, but in the persistent datastore. So any server will find what any other server previously stored in the session. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions):

> App Engine includes an implementation of sessions, using the servlet
>   session interface. The implementation stores session data in the App
>   Engine datastore for persistence, and also uses memcache for speed. As
>   with most other servlet containers, the session attributes that are
>   set with `session.setAttribute()` during the request are persisted at
>   the end of the request.
>
> This feature is off by default. To turn it on, add the following to
>   appengine-web.xml:
>
> ```
> <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
> ```
>
> The implementation creates datastore entities of the kind `_ah_SESSION`,
>   and memcache entries using keys with a prefix of `_ahs`.
>
> Note: Because App Engine stores session data in the datastore and
>   memcache, all values stored in the session must implement the
>   `java.io.Serializable` interface.
>
> It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your
>   application to asynchronously write HTTP session data to the
>   datastore:

Comment: It's worth noting that this capability is specific to the Java run time. Those of us who use Python and Go are still waiting for such a feature. There are, however, plenty of ways to add that capability, and a quick search on Google shows us that the problem has already been solved many times.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic scalability is what AppEngine does best and what most distinguishes it from other cloud-hosting providers. Both of your requirements are met without doing any extra work on your part.

AppEngine does not have a concept of individual servers. You can't think in such terms in creating a good, scaleable AppEngine app. You can, however, store client state between requests in Memcache or the Datastore, which are shared among all instances of application code.